# call PHP script within a .NET 2.0 web service

Tags: c#, php, .net, web-services, soap

I would like to make a HTTP web request from within a .NET 2.0 SOAP web service (written in C#). I cannot realize the call as a `[WebMethod]`, as this is an already existing PHP script which should be re-used in the web service.

The SOAP web service runs on IIS and the virtual directory is protected with NTLM authentication. The web service is running fine.
I have the following line in web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Windows" />
```

Inside a web method, I would like to call a function called convertString. This one calls a PHP script which translates a string. I tried various locations for the PHP script:

- in its original directory (protected by NTLM auth)

  in the web services virtual directory

  in a directory with anonymous access

In all three cases I get a HTTP error 401 - Unauthorized.
It only works when specifying username, password, and domain explicitly. But I would really like to avoid that.
Does anyone know, why this happens?

Here's the code of the function:

```
public string convertString(string raw)
{
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://server/directory/convtext.php?string=" + raw);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);  // This works! But I would like to avoid this line...
    // request.UseDefaultCredentials = true; // This does not work
    // request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials; // This does not work
    // request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials; // This does not work
    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
    StreamReader input = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
    return input.ReadToEnd();
}
```

(Pls. see the comments above. These are the calls I tried. Did I miss a method to specify credentials?)

Thanks guys,
Tom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I finally found out the solution for my problem.
Calling the php script from the .NET web service is working fine now.
I do not use authentication (I use anonymous access). The reason why it did NOT work before was not a wrong setting in the authentication settings (they had been set correctly to allow anonymous access) but a wrong setting in the AUTHORIZATION settings. So, not the AUTHENTICATION failed, but the AUTHORIZATION.
In other words, the anonymous user was granted access to the server but was not allowed to do anything on the server.
I added an allow rule in the authorization applet and now it works!

Answer (score 0):

I think the server is requesting basic authentication. Try with this:

```
System.Net.CredentialCache credentialCache = new System.Net.CredentialCache(); 
credentialCache.Add(
    new System.Uri("http://www.yoururl.com/"),
    "Basic", 
    new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password")
);
```

As you see it is very similar to your code:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://server/directory/convtext.php?string=" + raw);
    request.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(user, pass, domain);
```

Both work.

> If you want to avoid the line you have to **disable** the basic
>   authentication on the php web server. No other way to do it. You have to use
>   the authentication to show the server you are a valid user it basic is enabled,
>   or set it to public.

Comment: I already tried putting the script into a directory where authentication was disabled. I still received the error 401. As another option, I would re-use the same credentials that were used to call the web service. I do definitely not want to hard-code user name and password in the code.

Comment: Are you using apache?. Use the htpasswd.exe program that comes with your apache installation to create the .htpasswd_private. If you are using PHP with IIS just disable the basic authentication on the application

Comment: I'm using IIS. The PHP script lies on the same web server as the .NET web service (we have both ASP and PHP installed on the server). I switched off all authentication methods except anonymous authentication for the directory where the PHP script lies, but the 401 error still occurs. (Btw, on the SOAP web service I am using Windows authentication and I would like to re-use the same credentials used to authenticate to the web service also for the PHP script. The 2nd best choice would be anonymus access to the PHP scipt, but neither works.)